# StackApplet doesn't open / can't add account

Tags: 16.04, python, stackapplet

After installing [StackApplet](https://launchpad.net/stackapplet) by using:

```
sudo apt install stackapplet
```

The app doesn't open, so, it fixed by:

```
sudo apt-get install python-appindicator
```

Now it's open and appears in the indicator-panel, but,
when I try to add my account, the pop-up dialog for login authentication doesn't open, 
and the screen becomes dark but nothing else happens:

**The screen after pressing `Add a new account`:**
[image]

**The screen should look like this:**
[image]

In the browser console this errors comes up on launch:

```
jquery.js:9835 GET http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites?key=_qlxmEAOH06hLA1_FsZIGQ&jsonp=jQuery111304529615512861749_1478608610966&_=1478608610967 404 (Not Found)send @ jquery.js:9835ajax @ jquery.js:9214(anonymous function) @ (index):438fire @ jquery.js:3147fireWith @ jquery.js:3259ready @ jquery.js:3471completed @ jquery.js:3502
```

And on pressing `Add a new account`:

```
jqueryui.js:167 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined(…)width @ jqueryui.js:167create @ jqueryui.js:162overlay @ jqueryui.js:161open @ jqueryui.js:151_init @ jqueryui.js:148_createWidget @ jqueryui.js:30b.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) @ jqueryui.js:28(anonymous function) @ jqueryui.js:29each @ jquery.js:383each @ jquery.js:135b.fn.(anonymous function) @ jqueryui.js:29AddNew @ (index):212onclick @ (index):1
```

How may I add my account if the dialog can't open, please?

Comment: I'm wondering, as the code has not been updated since 2014-05-09, could this have something to do with it?

Comment: The code uses JavaScript, so it has to be enabled to work. In this case , however, it is not the issue. I've tested the applet just now - enabling JavaScript has no effect, so we can rule out that part of the mystery

Comment: It looks like a problem with Auth API which may have changed. As I read about some time ago that registering is not longer supported through v1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem this is how i fixed it.

**Doesnt show** - install `sudo apt-get install python-appindicator`

**Cant add account** - try the temporary fix first to see if it works then go for the permanent solution

http://ppa.launchpad.net/stackapplet-dev/stackapplet/ubuntu/pool/main/s/stackapplet/stackapplet_1.5.2-0~201406200412~ubuntu14.04.1_all.deb

i downloaded an older version and installed it and it works. you than run the app and add your user and then update the app using:

`sudo apt install stackapplet`

**This is a temporary fix.** As you will no longer be able to add an account because of a bug in the new version.

**Permanent Fix** - Which is what i have done

download the source files of the older stackapplet from this link:
http://ppa.launchpad.net/stackapplet-dev/stackapplet/ubuntu/pool/main/s/stackapplet/stackapplet_1.5.2-0~201406200416~ubuntu14.10.1.tar.xz

extract the files and then look for a folder called html. you need to replace the html folder used by the latest stackapplet with the older html folder.

the location of the html is: [/usr/share/stackapplet/html/
]

you will need root access to replace the files.

dont know how to do this. well here is the less technical way.
run this in terminal:

`sudo nautilus /usr/share/stackapplet/`

this will open up a file browser with root access. now just delete the html folder or rename it. Finally copy the html folder extracted from the archive.

**Your done, if you have the app open. close it run it again and it should all work. i havent tested everything but adding accounts and changing colour works. just not sure about autostart on login**

**Note** - the links are to the actual developers page. so can be trusted