# Alternatives to StackApplet?

Tags: stackapplet

I am experiencing problems with the program 'StackApplet' - the same as documented here [StackApplet doesn't open / can't add account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/847019/stackapplet-doesnt-open-cant-add-account). Since even after placing a bounty on this question (which is not mine) no-one has come forward with a solution I am looking  for an alternative to this program. i.e. A program that shows me my stackexchange inbox notifications and reputations changes as an applet on my desktop panel. What are such other alternatives?